# Book recommendations for Algebraic Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, book-recommendation

Can somebody suggest a good book for algebraic combinatorics please. I've been searching for good books but I am confused which one to buy.

Comment: That's a very vague request. Combinatorics is a pretty wide area, and the right book depends a lot on what you know and why you want such a book. You will get more useful answers if you are more specific.

Comment: Please do help me

Comment: Stanley's "Algebraic Combinatorics" is a pretty nice book.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: François Bergeron's book "Algebraic combinatorics and co-invariant spaces" is also nice.